# chromedriver not reachable after close and launch app. WebDriverException

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium, browserstack

I made test which close mobile app and after 2 seconds launch it.

```
self.welcome_page.confirm_continue()
self.driver.close_app()
sleep(2)
self.driver.launch_app()
sleep(1)
```

after than I get *WebDriverException* for every interaction with driver. (e.g. find_element, current_url, refresh ...)

On the screenshot and in the video I see that the app is in expected state and obviously launched successfully.

I am running tests against BrowserStack. with following BrowserCapabilities

```
[Android]
app=$APP_ID_ANDROID
AppfileName=$APP_NAME_ANDROID
AppCustomID=Corkscrew_andorid
autoAcceptAlerts=true
autoGrantPermissions=true
browserstack.debug=true
device=Samsung Galaxy Note 9
deviceName=Android Emulator
deviceOrientation=portrait
name=cs_test
os=android
os_version=8.1
no-reset=true
full-reset=false
autoWebview=true
```

response from Webdriver has old version of chromedriver.

```
'status': 100, 'value': {'message': 'chrome not reachable\n ...o: chromedriver=2.42.591071
```

appium logs: [HERE](https://pastebin.com/y50bq0ub)

**probably (I guess)** the driver is not active anymore and new one was created by launching app. But how can I get the new driver?

Comment: After you close the driver, you have to initialize the driver and DesiredCapabilities again.

Comment: @SubanDhyako
`launch_app()` does what you've described, doesn't?
GitHub appium: `default void launchApp()`
_Launches the app, which was provided in the capabilities at session creation, and (re)starts the session._

Comment: I would try switching driver.context() after you relaunch your app. I'm guessing that 'autoWebview=true' is not working on relaunch.